# Convert .mat file to R-compliant file

Tags: r, matlab

I am in the need of converting a MATLAB .mat file in something that can be read from R. Do you know some tools that can be used to perform such operation?

The .mat file contains cell matrices and struct matrices.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In recent releases, ".mat" files in Matlab are saved using the [HDF5](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HDF5) format that you can read in R with the package [hdf5](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/hdf5/)

Comment: Hi, thank you very much for your answer. Being on a Windows machine with R 2.13 I am having problems in finding a suitable package, though (it appears that the HDF5 has been discontinued for my platform). Do you have any other suggestion?

Comment: @Andrea -- it's not "discontinued," simply not built.  The ReadMe page at cran suggests it's because some of the dependencies are not built for 64-bit Windows.  However, you can always download the source package and build the executable on your machine.

Answer (score 3):

The R.matlab package provides a `readMat` function.

Answer (score 3):

There is also a package named [R.matlab](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/R.matlab/) that I didn't try but that seems available for Windows.